# I am able to call web service But Not able to get response from WEB SERVICE

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, web-services

I am trying to call web service using SQL. 
I am able to call web service properly but I am not able to response from Web service in **@vResponseText & @vStatusText**

**SQL CODE**

```
Declare @vStatus Int,@vResponseText Varchar(Max), @vStatusText Varchar(Max),@WsUrl Varchar(Max),@vPointer Int,@Parametres varchar(1000)
set @Parametres = '?Param1=11&Param2=11'
SET @WsUrl = 'http://192.168.123.227:4569/ASTRAX_WebService.asmx/CallTestMethod' + @Parametres

EXEC sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP', @vPointer OUTPUT
EXEC sp_OAMethod @vPointer, 'open', NULL, 'GET', @WsUrl 
EXEC sp_OAMethod @vPointer, 'send', NULL, @Parametres
EXEC sp_OAMethod @vPointer, 'responseText', @vResponseText OutPut
EXEC sp_OAMethod @vPointer, 'Status', @vStatus OutPut
EXEC sp_OAMethod @vPointer, 'StatusText', @vStatusText OutPut

EXEC sp_OADestroy @vPointer

Select @vStatus as Status, @vStatusText as StatusText, @vResponseText as ResponseText
```

**WEB SERVICE CODE**

```
[WebMethod]
public string CallTestMethod(string Param1, string Param2)
{
   return "I am called Successfully ..!!";
}
```

Expected Output :

```
I am called Successfully ..!!
```

Image of the output
[image]